# Accessing nested array of objects in Javascript

Tags: arrays, object

I have an array of objects (allCities) with a nested array of objects ("Residing City"). How can I loop through and access each "City" key's value?

```
  const allCities = [
      {   
         "Residing City": [
          {
            City: "Tokyo",
            Country: "Japan"
          },
          {
            City: "London",
            Country: "UK"
          },
          {
            City: "Paris",
            Country: "France"
          }
        ],
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
allCities[0]['Residing City'].forEach((t) => console.log(t.City))
```

You should read them once.
[Array Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through you can do it like this:

```
for (city of allCities[0]["Residing City"]) {
    console.log(city.City)
}
```

So `allCities[0]["Residing City"]` will return an array containing the **City objects**.
Now you can easily loop through the elements with a classic **for of loop** (you access directly the array value with `of`, instead accessing the index with `in`).