# Access nested array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, nested

I would like to loop throug nested array of objects but I have tried almost everything and I can't understand how it works.

I have object data that looks like:

```json
[
    {
       "restaurantName":"Bronco",
       "address":"39 Rue des Petites Écuries, 75010 Paris",
       "lat":48.8737815,
       "long":2.3501649,
       "ratings":[
          {
             "stars":4,
             "comment":"Un excellent restaurant, j'y reviendrai !Par contre il vaut mieux aimer la viande."
          },
          {
             "stars":5,
             "comment":"Tout simplement mon restaurant préféré !"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "restaurantName":"Babalou",
       "address":"4 Rue Lamarck, 75018 Paris",
       "lat":48.8865035,
       "long":2.3442197,
       "ratings":[
          {
             "stars":5,
             "comment":"Une minuscule pizzeria délicieuse cachéejuste à côté du Sacré choeur !"
          },
          {
             "stars":3,
             "comment":"J'ai trouvé ça correct, sans plus"
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
```

And I want to access the ratings to get the stars and comments, but I don't know how to do that.

I also get [object object] with `const coord =   { lat: el.lat, long:el.long };`

here is my code so far :

```js
fetch("http://localhost/ApiMap/data.json")
.then((response) => response.text())
.then(function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    //console.log(data);

    for (const el of data) {
        const name = el.restaurantName;
        const address = el.address;
        const coord =   { lat: el.lat, long:el.long };
        const tabRatings = el.ratings;
        init_resto(name, address, coord, tabRatings);
    }
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Il y a eu un problème avec l\'opération fetch: ' + error.message);
});
```

Comment: The code you have shown is fine, except that you should really not do `response.text()` and `JSON.parse`, but `response.json()` which does the parsing for you. I suppose you have a problem in `init_resto`? What exactly? You can loop over the ratings with `for (const rating of tabRatings)`: it is the same principle as you already applied by doing `for (const el of data)`...

Comment: hi, while making minor edits to your post, I also tried to fix the title to say 'Accessing' but it said that the question already existed. Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845571/accessing-nested-array-of-objects-in-javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach.

- Using Array.forEach() method. The forEach() method calls a function (a callback function) once for each array element.
- Inside callback function(dataFilter), value hold each object. Inside value `ratings` is a property. So we use `value.ratings` to get ratings data.
- `ratings` data is also an array, we loop through each of its elements also.

```js
var data = [
    {
       "restaurantName":"Bronco",
       "address":"39 Rue des Petites Écuries, 75010 Paris",
       "lat":48.8737815,
       "long":2.3501649,
       "ratings":[
          {
             "stars":4,
             "comment":"Un excellent restaurant, j'y reviendrai !Par contre il vaut mieux aimer la viande."
          },
          {
             "stars":5,
             "comment":"Tout simplement mon restaurant préféré !"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "restaurantName":"Babalou",
       "address":"4 Rue Lamarck, 75018 Paris",
       "lat":48.8865035,
       "long":2.3442197,
       "ratings":[
          {
             "stars":5,
             "comment":"Une minuscule pizzeria délicieuse cachéejuste à côté du Sacré choeur !"
          },
          {
             "stars":3,
             "comment":"J'ai trouvé ça correct, sans plus"
          }
       ]
    }
 ];
 
 function dataFilter(value, index, array){
 
    for(var i = 0; i< value.ratings.length; i++ ){
        console.log("comment: "+ value.ratings[i].comment);
        console.log("stars:" +value.ratings[i].stars);
    }
 }
 
data.forEach(dataFilter);
```